# Limit number of pages in will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, will-paginate

So, when using Sphinx searches are limited to 1000 results. But, if there are more than 1000 results pagination links generated by `will_paginate` don't take this into account, and provide links to pages beyond `1000/per_page`. Is the an obvious way setting a *max pages* or something similar?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best solution was to do this:

```
@results = Model.search(...)
if @results.total_pages >= (1000/Model.per_page)
  class << @results; def total_pages; 1000/Model.per_page; end end
end
```

Where the 1000 is preferably not hardcoded :). This gets you the correct behaviour of the will_paginate view helper for free,

Answer (score 13):

I think it's better to submit the parameter `:total_entries` to method `paginate`:

```
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30, 
                       :total_entries => 1000)
```

will_paginate will generate links only for the number of pages needed to show 1000 results.

You can also verify that the requested page belongs to the interval:

```
if params[:page].to_i * 30 <= 1000
  @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30, 
                         :total_entries => 1000)
end
```

Moreover, by submitting the parameter `:total_entries`, you avoid the sql COUNT query that will_paginate normally runs to retrieve the total number of entries.

Answer (score 2):

```
if params[:page].to_i * 30 <= 1000
  @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
end
```