# will_paginate gem : Limit number of pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination, will-paginate

[image]

This is my pagination, I want to limit the number of pages to 10, for example, to don't have the same problem as in the picture.

How can I do it using `will_paginate` gem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following command:

```
<%= will_paginate @yourwhatevers, inner_window: 3, outer_window: 1 %>
```

accomplishes this. Let's say you are on page 15 of 36, you will get:

```
Previous 1 2 ... 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 .. 35 36 Next
```

`inner_window`, in other words how many to the right and left from current page, defaults to 4, but for better, you could make it 1 or 2. outer_window defaults to 1, so my line above could not contain it at all

Comment: inner_window: 1, outer_window: 0  solve my problem. I have a problem with mobile devices like iPhone can't show the previous and next button because of too many pages on paginate section can't fit on mobile devices.

Answer (score 4):

There is quite a few ways to do it depending on that you want to do.  Check out this answer:

[Limit number of pages in will_paginate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173495/limit-number-of-pages-in-will-paginate)

One example with limiting it to 100 entries with 10 on a page (hence 10 pages)

```
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10, 
                       :total_entries => 100)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could limit the amount of results to be 10 times your page size:

```
MyModel.limit(300).paginate(page: params[:page])
```

That would mean you couldn't return any more than 300 results and therefore no more than 10 pages worth.

Alternatively you could explore some of the [`will_paginate` rendering options](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation#will_paginatecollection-options). You can configure the amount of pages display at the end of the pagination and around the current page - or even remove the page numbers altogether. For example:

```
will_paginate @results, inner_window: 1, outer_window: 1
```

will show `Previous | 1 | ... | 9 | ... | 16 | Next` for the example in the question.