# .limit and total_entries not working with will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

There's already a lot on this already ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173495/limit-number-of-pages-in-will-paginate)) but I can't seem to find anything that works. I simply want to limit the number of posts that are returned. I thought:

```
Post.order("created_at desc").limit(6).page(params[:page]).per_page(3)
```

would work but unfortunately not. I then tried:

```
Post.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(3).total_entries(6)
```

but that gives me a `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` error.

Comment: pagination already does things with limit... you may need to dig into what exactly it does and how to override specific parts of the scope...

Comment: Hmm, ok I'll dig. Thanks

Comment: Mainly I think because, it uses limit/offset to get just one page of data